# MySQL: Able to connect to localhost but not to 127.0.0.1

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am guessing I am forgetting something obvious, but I can't seem to connect to `127.0.0.1` using MySQL. Connecting via `localhost` works.

MySQL / Linux version: `Server version: 10.0.31-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 Ubuntu 16.04`

This works:

```
$ mysql -h localhost -u root
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 71982
Server version: 10.0.31-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 Ubuntu 16.04

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

This does *not* work:

```
$ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

It seems to me that MySQL is listening to `127.0.0.1:3306`:

```
$ netstat -plnt
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1841/mysqld
```

I can even connect to port 3306 using Telnet:

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 3306
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
j
5.5.5-10.0.31-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.2TGYk-=,d5-??wz}'Hr*s+u24mysql_native_password
```

Just in case, I have also created a user with grant option for host 127.0.0.1:

```
mysql > CREATE USER 'root'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY '<redacted>';
mysql > GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'127.0.0.1' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Here is some information about users (query suggested by @brian-ecker):

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT User, Host, plugin FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+-------------+
| User             | Host      | plugin      |
+------------------+-----------+-------------+
| root             | localhost | unix_socket |
| root             | 127.0.0.1 |             |
+------------------+-----------+-------------+
```

I have also tried creating a root user that is identified by unix_socket without it helping:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE USER 'root'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket;
MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'127.0.0.1' WITH GRANT OPTION;
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT User, Host, plugin FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+-------------+
| User             | Host      | plugin      |
+------------------+-----------+-------------+
| root             | localhost | unix_socket |
| root             | 127.0.0.1 | unix_socket |
+------------------+-----------+-------------+
```

Do you have any suggestions as to why I can connect via "localhost" but not "127.0.0.1"?

Comment: Have you tried with a password? `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p`. MySQL tries to connect using a socket when you use `localhost`, but it uses tcp when you connect to `127.0.0.1`, and the permissions can even be set differently for `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`, so maybe `127.0.0.1` has a password set, but `localhost` doesn't require it?

Comment: Yes I have: `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p` returns: `Enter password: ` and when I enter password I see this: `ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

Comment: Can you post the result of: `SELECT User, Host, plugin FROM mysql.user;`?

Comment: Sure. I have edited the original post with results of query.

Answer (score 10):

Solved it by adding this to MySQL configuration:

```
skip-name-resolve       = 1
```

From [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_skip_name_resolve):

> If it is OFF, mysqld resolves host names when checking client connections. If it is ON, mysqld uses only IP numbers; in this case, all Host column values in the grant tables must be IP addresses or localhost.

Comment: Keep in mind that it might also be possible that you miss [`FLUSH PRIVILEGES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privilege-changes.html) when needed or that the host `localhost` is a special separated login besides "normal" IP hosts as `127.0.0.1`. Or maybe a combination of both. Changing this server setting was most likely not needed, but maybe a server restart/flush privileges was.

Comment: This fixed it for me too - MariaDB 10.1.26 (Debian Stretch). Most annoying behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

I've battled with this on MariaDB 10.1.26 on Debian 9. I found that using `root` as username *simply doesn't work* if you want to connect using TCP, on `127.0.0.1`, or wherever.

In the end, I created another user with global privileges – no issues.

Comment: Found any solution to this? I've your situation: on MariaDB 10.1.31/Debian 9 I can connect as `root` using `localhost` (socket), both with or without password (`unix_socket` plugin in the latter). However I can't connect as `root@127.0.0.1`. I also enabled `skip-name-resolve` but no success (at least I'm now sure I'm using TCP and not socket). Creating another user works.

Comment: Nope, never found a solution.

Comment: It seems like the Debian team recompiled the source of MariaDB disabling this feature, but I cannot find anything in documentation. I have no time at the moment, but it would be nice to try with official MariaDB packages instead of Debian ones, or try tro contact the Debian maintainers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you wanted to use unix sockets in the case of localhost. However, connecting to 127.0.0.1 works again if you just don't use the "unix_socket" plugin. E.g. do the following:

```
UPDATE user SET plugin = '' 
WHERE user = 'root' AND host = 'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

A drawback of this solution is that you can no longer use MySQL root login from the system's root account; i.e. accessing MySQL root without entering a password; e.g. mysql -u root -h localhost will no longer work.